# Newrelic install for Android that does not use ant

Tags: android, ant, monitoring, newrelic

I want to install Newrelic to monitor my Android app.
I have successfully integrated the SDK using ant. 
However, I prefer using a code library rather than linking my code with their .class.

The Newrelic documentation doesn't mention a non ant way to install Newrelic, here - http://newrelic.wistia.com/medias/rzbz77365w.

I noticed the Newrelic staff answer questions here in SO, so maybe one of them can assure me that using ant is the only supported solution at the moment?

Comment: define not possible.  We need to see what you have tried to help.

Comment: no i don't think so. I also tried it without success.

Comment: not possible at the moment, from what I understood, they inject their code during the build-step, because that is the way they do it with native Java applications as well. they said they are working on a solution, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to this: the latest SDK now includes an Eclipse and Maven plugin and a much-improved Ant build process as well.

Comment: There is also a Gradle plugin now :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the response by the `newrelic` support group:

> Currently we don't have a library offering for New Relic for Mobile Apps, since we implement complete instrumentation of network calls right at build time, a library option isn't workable with our current implementation.

Comment: Accurate but out of date, Eclipse, Maven, and Gradle are now all supported.